# Infinitesimal symmetry of a tangent distribution.

Tags: differential-geometry, symmetry, tangent-bundle

An infinitesimal symmetry of a tangent distribution $D={\rm span}(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ on $n$-dimensional manifold $M$ is a vector field $Y$ such that for every $X\in D$ a Lie bracket $[X,Y]\in D$.

My question is: How do computations look like in a case where $D={\rm span}(X_1:=\partial_z)$, where $M=(x,y,z,t)$? How to find all infinitesimal symmetries of $D$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be a bit careful: you really mean that for any $X\in\Gamma(D)$ (i.e. $X$ a section of $D$, a linear combination of the vector fields $X_i$ with possibly non-constant coefficients), then $[X,Y] \in\Gamma(D)$. In your case, the general section looks like 
$$X = f(x,y,z,t)\,\partial_z.$$ 
Then you should take an arbitrary vector field 
$$ Y = a(x,y,z,t)\,\partial_x + b(x,y,z,t)\,\partial_y + c(x,y,z,t)\,\partial_z + d(x,y,z,t)\,\partial_t,$$
and find under what conditions $[X,Y]\in\Gamma(D)$, i.e. $[X,Y]\propto \partial_z$. The condition turns out to be that $a, b, d$ don't depend on $z$.

Comment: Yes you are right, I should be more careful. May I ask you to write down these symmetries in a direct way, because I steel can’t find them?

Comment: Do you know how to calculate the commutator $[X,Y]$ of two vector fields? If so, do it for the above vector fields, and then impose that all $\partial_x, \partial_y,$ and $\partial_t$ terms vanish.

Comment: The infinitesimal symmetries look like $Y=a(x,y,t)\,\partial_x + b(x,y,t)\,\partial_y + c(x,y,z,t)\,\partial_z + d(x,y,t)\,\partial_t$, where $a,b,c,d$ are arbitrary functions of the indicated variables.